# ListView wrong selection on ItemLongClistener

Tags: android, listview

I have a method that paint the View of selected item but if my ListView has a scroll ( i mean: if my screen can display 9 "lines" - positions - and the total size is bigger than 9 ) and i select one the first nine positions, it will select the position that i choose and one from the last positions ( a position that i need to scroll to see ).

Example: if i select select the position 0 and paint it, the view on position 0 and on position 11 will be painted.

If i try do to:

```
getListView().getChildAt(int)
```

And if this position is like '12', it will return null so i'm using the View that i get when onItemLongClick(AdapterView adapterView, View v, int position , long arg3) is called. It looks like that View is based on scroll because i have same View objects for scroll positions.

Here is how i paint the Views:

```
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v,
                int position , long arg3) {
            Log.d("", "");

            View tmp = adapterView.getChildAt(position);

            int oi = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();

            if(!mPositions.contains(Integer.valueOf(position))){
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                mViews.add(v);
                mPositions.add(Integer.valueOf(position));
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mViews.remove(v);
                mPositions.remove(Integer.valueOf(position));
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

How can i get distinct views independently if the list is bigger than my screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you really shouldn't be modifying the view directly.  The whole point of a ListView is that it will create a view for an item, and then potentially use this same view to paint each and every one of the items in the list.  (row recycling).  It is possible here, that when you modify the background colour of the selected item's view, this view object is then actually being used to draw another row's items - looking like it's just doing it for the wrong row.

What you should do, is create a custom adapter with your own implementation of getView().  Inside this function you will do one of two things:  If convertView is null, then create the View that you desire (possibly a TextView?), otherwise you will grab the view from convertView.  Finally you will then set this view up however you would like based on it's position in the list.  Ie: if it's text, set the value, and then set your background.

To respond to the longpress, simply change your data (mSeleted) and call notifyDataSetChanged() so that the list will redraw based on this new data.

This is a pretty simplistic overview, listviews can get as complicated as you want.  There are many examples of how to create a custom listview on the web if you search.

Comment: Got it. So i should change my implementation to add a listener on my custom adapter, right? I was wondering if i could use an action bar in mine Adapter. All implementations that i've found, uses action bar on ListActivity.

Comment: Yes, your listener would update the data in your custom adapter and then notify your list that the data has changed (and therefore cause a repaint).  Your custom adapter would then configure the view to display differently depending on the data it is provided.